# Xuggler-Java-How to write the header of a IStreamContainer for .mp4 and/or .avi?

Tags: java, header, mp4, avi, xuggle

Does anybody know how to set/add additional information to the header of an IStreamContainer for .mp4 format type  and/or .avi? 
Using writeHeader  for the Icontainer is not giving the right thing beacuse the resulting file contains frames that cannot be visualized in VLC.